# filter a checkedlistbox with a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

On my form stands a checkedlistbox which i want to filter with a textbox. I tried this, but nothing happens. Which part is wrong?

```
List<string> ListCheckboxItems = new List<string>();  //new

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  //new
    {
        var filteredItems =
            ListCheckboxItems.Where(item => ListCheckboxItems.Contains(item));


        checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();

        foreach (object item in filteredItems)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `item => ListCheckboxItems.Contains(item)` is always true. You need `item => item.Contains(textBox1.Text)`

Comment: You have an empty `List<string>` on which you apply the Where method. Of course this returns nothing. Then you clear the CheckdListBox1 from everything and try to add something from the empty filteredItems variable. This code makes no sense in the context of the question asked. Can you clarify better what is your objective?

Comment: I forgot to tell that i fill the list in the form load with foreach (object item in  GetItemsDataTable(this.columnName))
            {
                ListCheckboxItems.Add(item.ToString());             }  //I can see in the debugger that the list has values

Comment: Found it. i had to copy filteredItems to a list.